# How to add pallet bounties on runtime?

Tags: pallet

I am building a solo chain from [Substrate node template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template). I am trying to add `pallet-bounties` on top of the runtime. I can't seem to figure out a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by going over the tutorials especially this one:

- https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-application-logic/add-a-pallet

One trick that I always use is to see how it is configured in the "kitchensink" node where you will see many pallet configured.

Check this out:

- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/86fde367c0b10303b71a5f52857e254a2ee1e953/substrate/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1238-L1262

If you get stuck, perhaps start by practicing integrating more basic pallet into your runtime. The process of integrating pallets in your runtime are all pretty much the same once you get the hang of configuring one or two pallets then you will know how to do most of them.